# solving an irrational equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus, problem-solving

I want to solve this equation

$$\sqrt{x+3} + \sqrt{2x+4} = 12-\sqrt{3x+7}$$

I tried the given equation equivalent to 
$$ \sqrt{(x+3)(2x+4)} = 72-12\sqrt{3x+7}$$

I see that, that equation has unique solution $x = 6$ but I can not solve. How can I solve this equation or solve the given equation with another way?

Comment: @davis: Square each side and simplify until you get rid of the radicals - you will find $x = 6$.

Comment: Did you mean $\sqrt{(x + 3)(2x + 4)} = 72 - \color{red}{12}\sqrt{3x + 7}$?

Comment: @ N. F. Taussig. Yes!

Comment: If you know that the solution is $x=6$,then since left side is strictly increasing and right side is strictly decreasing that implies that $x=6$ is the only solution

Comment: Put one radical by itself to one side of the equation..  Square.  Put one of the remaining radicals by itself square.  That gets rid of radicals.  Solve quadratic.  Check answers to eliminate extraneous false solutions.

Comment: Forget the successive squarings and focus on what @kingW3 said.